# How do you link to a specific product variant on an Ali Express product page?

Tags: aliexpress

## Question

When you link to a product on Ali Express, it just links to the general product page, not the specific product variant (colour, size, etc).

**How can one set the URL parameters of an Ali Express product page so the product variant is selected?**

## Example

This product page links to a product with variants of the following parameters:

```
{colour, length}
```

[5A USB C to USB Type C Cable...](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html)

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html
```

<kbd>[image: Ali Express item without variant selected]</kbd>

But when you click one of the colour and one of the length variants, the URL doesn't change.

When clicking through to this product page from a Search Result Page (SRP) (3rd result from [Ali Express Search: `usb+cable`](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=usb+cable), it seems that the important URL parameter that gets set is the `pdp_ext_f` parameter, as seen here:

[5A USB C to USB Type C Cable...: (product variant selected)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html?pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000023061487047%22%7D)

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html
    ?pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000023061487047%22%7D
```

<kbd>[image: Ali Express item with product variant selected]</kbd>

Which, when decoded, shows this value:

```
pdp_ext_f={"sku_id":"12000023061487047"}
```

## Followup Question

How does one figure out the value of the JSON key `sku_id`, in the URL parameter: `pdp_ext_f`, to select a particular product variant on a product page?

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

The easiest way to figure out the `sku_id`, is to click the "Buy Now" button, and extract it from the URL parameters on that buy page:

## Instructions

1. Open and Ali Express product page, such as:

   [5A USB C to USB Type C Cable...](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html) (`https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002964689678.html`)
2. Click the "Buy Now" button (don't worry, it won't actually buy anything)
3. Extract the `skuId` parameter value from the resultant page URL
4. Press `Back` on your browser to go back to the product page of the item
5. Clean the Ali Express product page URL by ensuring there are no URL parameters (delete `?` and everything after it, which will be after the `.html` in the URL)
6. Add the URL parameter and value to the end of the clean product URL by pasting this to the end of the URL, replacing `SKU_ID_VALUE` with the value extracted earlier:

```
?pdp_ext_f=%7B"sku_id":"SKU_ID_VALUE"%7D
```

7. Press enter to load the modified URL, and notice that the product variant is selected